# Does the wave function contain the information of the particle's mass?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, wavefunction

It is said that wave function contains "all" the information about a particle but I don't see how I can get the mass from wave function. Further, it is able to judge what kind of particle it is by simply looking at its wave function? If not, it this why in quantum field theory we build different equations for different kind of particles(eg KG equation for scalar particles, Dirac eqn for electrons)?

Answer (score 4):

> Does the wave function contain the information of the particle's mass?

The answer depends on what you mean by wavefunction.

If you mean the whole time-dependent wavefunction $\psi(\mathbf{x},t)$ in the **Schrödinger picture**, then the answer is yes. The time-dependence of this function is determined by the time-evolution operator (Hamiltonian), in which the particle's mass is an explicit parameter.

If you mean the time-agnostic wavefunction $\psi(\mathbf{x})$ in the **Heisenberg picture**, or a **single-time slice** of the Schrödinger-picture wavefunction, then the answer is no.

In either case, the statement that the wave function contains "all" the information about a particle is valid only within the context of a specific *model*, which means that all of the relevant observables have already been specified for all times. The only thing the model doesn't specify is the particle's initial state; that's what the wavefunction specifies.

---

### Quantum field theory

In QFT, things like the Klein-Gordon (KG) equation and the Dirac equation are examples of Heisenberg equations of motion for the **field operators**. The field operators are not wavefunctions. The field operators are the material from which *observables* are constructed. (In some cases, they are observables themselves.) The analog of the wavefunction in QFT is a state-vector in the Hilbert space on which those field operators act.

---

### A unifying perspective

This all becomes more clear when we adopt a consistent conceptual approach to all models, one that works just as well in relativistic QFT as it does in non-relativistic QM: the state of the system is represented by an element of the Hilbert space on which the observables act, and the model is specified by specifying which operators on the Hilbert space represent which physical observables.

Starting from that perspective, we can easily switch to whatever other perspectives are most convenient in particular cases. For example, instead of directly specifying all of the observables for all times, we usually specify only the observables at a single time, and then specify the Hamiltonian that defines how those observables change with time. That's in the Heisenberg picture, and of course we can also switch to the Schrödinger picture, if desired. In nonrelativistic QM, we can choose to represent elements of the Hilbert space as wavefunctions on which the components of the position operator act as a multiplication operators: 
$$
X_n\psi(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_n\psi(x_1,x_2,x_3).
$$
(As written, this example assumes a model of a single spinless particle.) This is just one way to represent elements of the Hilbert space, one that is especially convenient for many applications.